# How to sort macros in TeXstudio in alphabet order

Tags: macros, texstudio

I am using TeXstudio 3.0.1. I see it is very useful to use macros for fast typing. As you can see in the figure, I created a number of macros.

[image]

I see that the macros are sorted as the time I created them. I now want to sort them in the alphabet order because after some days, I cannot remember what I created. By sorting, I can quickly see whether the new macro is needed or not.

I can manually do that by using the up and down buttons but that is inefficient, I think.

Do you have any better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

(This answer didn't provide step-by-step guides, but only some rough info.)

User defined texstudio macros are stored in files `Macro_<n>.txsMacro` in the subfolder "macro" under [setting path](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#where-are-the-settings-stored), one file per macro. For example, on macOS

```
> tree ~/.config/texstudio/macro
/Users/guten/.config/texstudio/macro
├── Macro_0.txsMacro
├── Macro_1.txsMacro
└── Macro_2.txsMacro
```

Here the numbers `0`, `1`, `2` represent the order shown in "Edit Macros" window, And the contents of each `.txsMacro` is a JSON file, with the macro name stored in key `"name"`.
Below is the contents of a `.txsMacro` corresponding to a dummy macro.

```json
{
    "abbrev": "",
    "description": [
        ""
    ],
    "formatVersion": 1,
    "menu": "",
    "name": "name2",
    "shortcut": "",
    "tag": [
        ""
    ],
    "trigger": ""
}
```

Hence (theoretically) the task can be achieved by renaming these `.txsMacro` files by the alphabetic order of their `"name"` key.